# How to count the number of result sets returned by a stored procedure? (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Actually I have a Stored Procedure(which takes a object as input) which return either two or three table(Result sets). Now i have to categorized the objects by the no of result sets. How can i do it in programmatic way?? 
The procedure is non-editable. Otherwise it was a small job which was done by adding a flag.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: show some examples or look here  on how to ask a good question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You should specify how you are calling stored procedure!

Comment: I'm calling the stored procedure through another procedure(which has a loop)..

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of successful `NextResult()` calls to your `SqlDataReader`.

**Update** following the discussion in comments.

Result sets become available immediately. That means, the first one can become available long before stored procedure completion and as long as the procedure is running there is no way (apart from the source code analysis) to determine how many more result sets would still become available. So, you need to run the procedure to the end, get all the result sets and only then you would be able to count them properly. What you suggest is effectively running stored procedure on SQL Server to the end and analyzing there how many result sets became available. That can (sort of) be done through [`EXEC ... WITH RESULT SETS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) (SQL Server 2012 and on) with error handling but that's going to be drastically inefficient.

If you can create a new procedure why not re-implement the existing one with an extra return value?

Comment: Are there no way to get it done by **SQL Server only**?

Comment: Yes. That's why i'm thinking about to create a new procedure and call the previous procedure and count the no of tables. are there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset and fill it by calling the stored procedure. Then count the tables of the dataset.

Comment: Are there no way to get it done by SQL Server only? I'm thinking about to create a new procedure and call the previous procedure and count the no of tables. are there any way to do it?